# Why am I able to adjust "vertical_speed" with all mouse buttons instead of only button "9"?

Tags: lua

```lua
local vertical_speed = 1

function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents (true)

        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            local frac, x, y = 0, 2

            repeat
                Sleep(10)
                x, y, frac = -x, math.modf(frac + vertical_speed)
                MoveMouseRelative(x * 2, y)
            until x > 0 and not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end

        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9 then

        elseif IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
            vertical_speed = vertical_speed + 1
        elseif IsModifierPressed("lalt") then
            vertical_speed = 1
        end
    end
end
```

I want to be able to increase `vertical_speed` up with button "9" while holding "shift", and reset while holding "alt". The script works except it's adjustable with all mouse buttons instead of only button "9".

I'm rather new to Lua, and I'm sure it's something very obvious that I can't see.

Comment: Nothing is inside `if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9 then`; `elseif` closes it.

Comment: "I'm sure it's something very obvious that I can't see" thank you, I knew I was blind.